# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$date = "2016-12-14 00:00";
$dt_format = "d/m/Y H:i";
$date = date_create_from_format($dt_format, $date);
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $date;`
?>
```

This is showing Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

What is wrong in this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function format() on boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293221/call-to-a-member-function-format-on-boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way with procedural way that you followed all alone. Why are you mixing up both OOP and Procedural way?. Use any one of them. See more info here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

**Procedural:**

```
   $date = "2016-12-14 00:00";
   $dt_format = "Y-m-d H:i";
   $date = date_create_from_format($dt_format, $date);
   echo date_format($date, $dt_format);
```

**OOP:**

```
   $date = "2016-12-14 00:00";
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($dt_format, $date);
   echo $date->format($dt_format);
```