# Call to a member function format() on boolean

Tags: php, date

I want to find the difference between two dates and I have used `date_diff` for the same. When format function is applied on `date_diff` object it returns an error.

> **Call to a member function format() on boolean**

**`$field_value`** is fetched from the database and it's format is **`dd/mm/YYYY`**. When I hard-code the values for **`$field_value`** and **`$indexing_value`** the following code works.

Everything is running fine till line number 8. I have tried outputting the value of

```
$diff->format("%R%a")
```

and it is returning exact value but the code gives error near the if statement.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$current_date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
$indexing_value = str_replace("/", "-", $field_value);
$current_value = str_replace("/", "-", $current_date);
$indexing_value = date_create($indexing_value);
$current_value = date_create($current_value);

$diff = date_diff($indexing_value, $current_value);
if ($diff->format("%R%a") < 0) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "2";
}
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add condition to check whether you got the diff or not, as it returns false if there is error . Check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) for the same

```
$diff = date_diff($indexing_value, $current_value);
if ($diff) {
    if ($diff->format("%R%a") < 0) {
        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo "2";
    }   
}
```

You are getting error because for some values the diff is not calculated and have value `False` in `$diff`

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know what is wrong with the above code.

There are several issues with the code:

1. You don't check the values returned by [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php); it returns [`FALSE` on error](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-returnvalues).
2. What's the point of formatting `$date` then creating `$current_value` back from the resulting string? If you don't care about the time components and need to use only the date part of a `DateTime` object you can use its `setTime()` method to set the time components to `0`.
3. What's the point of using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to manipulate the text representation of a date when you know its format? [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) can be used to parse the string into a `DateTime` object.
4. There is no need to compute the difference of the two dates and the format it and compare the value to `0`. The `DateTime` objects can be compared directly.

All in all, all the code you need is:

```
// Current date & time
$today = new DateTime();
// Ignore the time (change $today to "today at midnight")
$today->setTime(0, 0, 0);

// Parse the value retrieved from the database
$field = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $field_value);
// We don't care about the time components of $field either (because the time
// is not provided in the input string it is created using the current time)
$field->setTime(0, 0, 0);

// Directly compare the DateTime objects to see which date is before the other
if ($field < $today) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "2";
}
```